# pass http://yousite/sample.mp3 to external android app to stream

Tags: audio, android-intent

I have a link `http://yousite/sample.mp3` and I want to pass it to default audio player in android:
I'm doing:

```
RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setType("audio/mp3");
startActivity(intent);
```

and it says:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=audio/mp3 }
```

if I omit `intent.setType("audio/mp3");` it opens in the Browser with audio player in it which is clearly not what I want. I then tried to share:

```
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

and there was no application found to share to!